# How Do I insert a schema_migration record on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, schema-migration

I was successful in resolviong this issue locally:

[I am missing a migration file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13653494/i-am-missing-a-migration-file)

but am now trying to duplicate the feat on Heroku and do not know how to access the database there. Can anyone guide me through the process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open a PSQL session and use the same SQL you used locally:

```
heroku pg:psql [DATABASE]
```

Comment: Great, thanks. Mine looked like this: heroku pg:psql HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_WHITE_URL